# Python, loop program

Tags: loops, python-3.x

Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong? I am writing a program using loops in Python 3.x, but when i execute program i am getting a traceback error:

multiple of 13 is 195 and factors are as follows
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Darlene/Desktop/Chapter 4/program4_2.py", line 19, in 
    list1.append(j)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'

this is the code i entered:

```
def main():
    for i in reversed(list(range(100,201))):
    if i%13==0:
        print("multiple of 13 is",i,"and factors are as follows")
        list1 = {}
        for j in list(range(2,i+1)):
            if i%j == 00:
            list1.append(j)
        print(list1)
main()
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, `list1 = {}` declares a dictionary, not a list, thus there is no `append` method associated with it.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by Luke Park, `list1 = {}` will declare a dictionary. What you need is `list1 = []`.

Also, range will already return a [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#ranges) type that can be handled by most methods and loops so there's no need to cast it to a list.

Answer (score 0):

list1 must be an list like so...

```
list1 = []
```

you defined it as an dict, and as python said

'dict' object has no attribute 'append'